# How to extract content URL from WordPress Database in Java?

Tags: java, wordpress, etl

I have a connection to an external WP database with read-only privileges. I import published posts from this DB which is pretty simple.

However, I also need to import online urls for the imported posts. I can't get it directly from the DB since field *guid* field doesn't correspond to the website url. I need to extract information related to 
get_permalink from WP API, but I work on isolated Java-based system with only DB connection with WP. Do you have any suggestion how to extract URL from this DB?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/